# Understanding booking dot com's "Free Cancellation" Policy

Tags: bookings, hotels, refunds, booking.com

I booked some hotel and due to different reasons, had to cancel. I had booked with free cancellation no pre-payment (I did not read it at the time of booking as I wasn't expecting to cancel). I paid anyway as I prefer to have things sorted in advance, and have been sent a refund receipt by booking dot com. The refund receipt says

> Your reservation at Hotel was recently cancelled. We’ve issued you a refund of X amount.
>
> It should be credited to your account in 7-12 days.

Have I been fully refunded, or is there a chance the hotel could charge me? I texted the hotel and they confirmed cancellation but could not guarantee a refund as it "depends on if I booked non-refundable". The fine print on booking dot com takes me back to "Free cancellation by X date". Am I good? In your experience, how long is the account credited if successful?

Comment: Did you cancel before "X date" or not ?

Comment: Thanks, I canceled before X date.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have used that clause for some of my bookings. It's just legalese for "we don't know how long will it take for your bank to show the refund on your account, don't freak out".

If you have canceled within the allowed day, you will get the full refund.

Comment: Just a note for future users, I got my refund today one working day (technically) later. So that was fast!

Comment: @NelsonGon The long time in the email is a CYA move.